# How can I compare two video files with ffmpeg, using PSNR?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I found this command in another thread

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -i input_video.mp4 -i reference_video.mp4 -filter_complex "psnr" -f null /dev/null
```

With the output

```
PSNR y:13.742690 u:28.560843 v:28.912792 average:15.435325 min:3.238622 max:39.985814
```

However, this seems to only be giving the output for one of the videos, not comparing them. What am I doing wrong?

Or is there a simpler way to compare the 'quality' of two video files?

Comment: A comparison of two files will produce one result. This is the main value: `average:15.435325`

Comment: @Gyan But how do I interpret this? Does it mean the input scores higher or the referenced?

Comment: The input cannot score higher. The result indicates how close the input is to the reference. 60 means almost identical. 45 is pretty close.

Comment: So in this instance, 15.43... means that the referenced video is 15.43, on average, worse? Or is it just 15,43 'different' ?

Comment: @Gyan also, add an answer so I can reward you :D